# Why does it make a difference to insert an ELF into a SQLite3 database via console or python

Tags: python, sqlite, console, executable, elf

When I insert an ELF into a SQLite database via the command:

```
$ sqlite3 insert into TABLE values('name', readfile('executable'));
```

I can execute the extracted pendant to it. But when I insert the blob file via the following python command:

```
>>> cursor.execute('''INSERT INTO table(Name,Executable) VALUES(?,?)''',('name',sqlite3.Binary(file)))
```

I get the error message

> cannot execute binary file: Fehler im Format der Programmdatei

So it seems that `sql.Binary()` changes the file. The ELF extracted after the second method is way smaller than the other one.

Whan am I doing wrong? Actually both methods should do the same, right?

Comment: Which console is the "console" in the 1st example? It doesn't look as either shell, python or an SQL client.

Comment: Its ubuntu console typing the line obove

Answer (score 0, accepted):

io.open() is doing the job. It doesn't convert the file to octet-stream